# SQL Materias Disponibles para una Carrera

Tags: php, sql, firebird

Buenas noches amigos, tengo días matándome con un SQL que no consigo la forma de hacer, les cuento estoy desarrollando un sistema para la gestión de universidades, y estoy atrapando en el listado de materias disponibles.
Tengo estas tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE EST_CARRERAS (
    CCARRERA              CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CODIGO                DESCRIPCION_CORTA DEFAULT 'NONE' NOT NULL /* DESCRIPCION_CORTA = VARCHAR(50) */,
    DESCRIPCION           DESCRIPCION_MEDIA NOT NULL /* DESCRIPCION_MEDIA = VARCHAR(120) */,
    ESTATUS               LOGICO DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL /* LOGICO = INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL */
);

CREATE TABLE EST_MATERIAS (
    CMATERIA              CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CODIGO                DESCRIPCION_CORTA DEFAULT 'NONE' /* DESCRIPCION_CORTA = VARCHAR(50) */,
    DESCRIPCION           DESCRIPCION_MEDIA NOT NULL /* DESCRIPCION_MEDIA = VARCHAR(120) */
);

CREATE TABLE EST_MAT_CAR (
    CMATE                 CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CMATERIA              CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CCARRERA              CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    SEMESTRE              INTEGER DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE EST_MAT_PRES (
    CPRESLA               CODIGO /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CMATERIA              CODIGO /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CPRESLACION           CODIGO /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CCARRERA              CODIGO /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CTIPO                 CODIGO /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CANT                  MONTOS /* MONTOS = DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT 0.0 */
);

CREATE TABLE EST_INSCRIPCION (
    CINSCRIPCION          CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CCARRERA              CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CPERIODO              CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CALUMNO               CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    FINSCRIPCION          FECHA NOT NULL /* FECHA = DATE */
);

CREATE TABLE EST_INSCRIPCION_DET (
    CINSCRIPCION_DET      CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CINSCRIPCION          CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CMATE                 CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    CSECCION              CODIGO NOT NULL /* CODIGO = INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL */,
    NOTA                  MONTOS /* MONTOS = DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT 0.0 */
);
```

Entonces la primera tabla maneja las carreras, la 2da las materias,la 3ra la relación materia - carrera (cmate) la 4ta tabla la prelación de las materias (cmateria: materia a ver o evaluar, cpreslacion: materia que tubo que haberse aprobado para ver la cmateria, ctipo=si es 2 entra en juego CANT que son la cantidad de UC aprobadas), las siguientes 2 son la cabecera y los detalles de las inscripciones, entonces hice un pequeño ejemplo donde a un registro de inscripción (est_inscripcion) le inserte 3 lineas (donde repeti 1 materia 2 veces) para verificar que el select me traiga las materias disponibles de una carrera en cuestion:

```
SELECT
MC.CMATE,
M.CMATERIA,
M.DESCRIPCION,
C.CCARRERA,
C.DESCRIPCION
FROM EST_MAT_CAR MC
INNER JOIN EST_MATERIAS M ON MC.CMATERIA=M.CMATERIA
INNER JOIN EST_CARRERAS C ON MC.CCARRERA=C.CCARRERA
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
DISTINCT(ID.CMATE)
FROM
EST_INSCRIPCION_DET ID
INNER JOIN EST_INSCRIPCION I ON ID.CINSCRIPCION=I.CINSCRIPCION
WHERE ID.NOTA > 10
AND I.CALUMNO=1
AND I.CCARRERA=1) ID2 ON ID2.CMATE=MC.CMATE
WHERE ID2.CMATE IS NULL
AND C.CCARRERA=1
```

El select me trae todas las materias que el alumno puede ver, pero me esta trayendo una materia que debería de poder ver puesto que "choca" con una que no ha aprobado, (en eso interviene est_mat_pres) pero no se como hacer dicho select para que me traiga las materias disponibles y si de dichas materias aparece una que esta en el campo cpreslacion, no me muestre del campo cmateria en el listado.

No se si me entienden, pero estoy muy enredado y no consigo la repuesta. El sistema lo estoy haciendo en PHP y presumo que tendre que hacer una especie de BUCLE, pero buscaba la forma mas eficaz de hacerlo a través de un SELECT.

Comment: Podrías agregar el ejemplo que hiciste. Es decir, los registros que insertaste en cada tabla, el resultado que te da y el resultado que debería dar (el resultado correcto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Junto con mi compañero de proyecto logramos crear un procedimiento que hace el trabajo de listar las materias disponibles:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ALUM_MATERIAS_PENDIENTES(
    P_ALUMNO TYPE OF CODIGO,
    P_CARRERA TYPE OF CODIGO)
RETURNS(
    MAT_COD TYPE OF DESCRIPCION_CORTA,
    MAT_CODE TYPE OF CODIGO,
    MAT_NAME TYPE OF DESCRIPCION_CORTA,
    COD_CARRERA TYPE OF CODIGO,
    DESCRIP_CARRERA TYPE OF DESCRIPCION_CORTA,
    MAT_SEM INTEGER)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE V_CCARRERA TYPE OF CODIGO;
DECLARE VARIABLE V_CMATERIA TYPE OF CODIGO;
DECLARE VARIABLE V_PRELACION INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE V_CTIPO INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE V_CANT INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE V_UC INTEGER;
BEGIN
  /* DESCRIPCION: DEVUELVE LAS MATERIAS PENDIENTES POR APROBAR, VALIDANDO LAS PRELACIONES
  */

  IF (P_ALUMNO IS NULL OR P_CARRERA IS NULL) THEN
  EXIT;

  /*UN CICLO POR CADA UNA DE LAS MATERIAS QUE PERTENECEN A LA CARRERA NO APROBADAS*/
  FOR SELECT
            M.CODIGO,
            M.CMATERIA,
            M.DESCRIPCION,
            C.CCARRERA,
            C.DESCRIPCION,
            MC.SEMESTRE
       FROM EST_MAT_CAR MC
       JOIN EST_MATERIAS M ON MC.CMATERIA=M.CMATERIA
       JOIN EST_CARRERAS C ON MC.CCARRERA=C.CCARRERA
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT (ID.CMATE)
               FROM EST_INSCRIPCION_DET ID
               JOIN EST_INSCRIPCION I ON (ID.CINSCRIPCION = I.CINSCRIPCION)
              WHERE ID.NOTA >= 10
                AND I.CALUMNO = :P_ALUMNO
                AND I.CCARRERA = :P_CARRERA) ID2 ON (ID2.CMATE = MC.CMATE)
       WHERE ID2.CMATE IS NULL
         AND C.CCARRERA = :P_CARRERA
               INTO :MAT_COD,
                    :MAT_CODE,
                    :MAT_NAME,
                    :COD_CARRERA,
                    :DESCRIP_CARRERA,
                    :MAT_SEM

        DO BEGIN

        /*VALIDO SI LA MATERIA TIENE ALGUN TIPO DE PRELACION*/
        IF (EXISTS (SELECT P.CMATERIA
                      FROM EST_MAT_PRES P
                     WHERE P.CMATERIA = :MAT_CODE AND P.CCARRERA = :COD_CARRERA)) THEN

                     /*BUSCO CON QUIEN TIENE PRELACION*/
                 FOR SELECT P.CPRESLACION,
                            P.CCARRERA,
                            P.CTIPO,
                            P.CANT
                       FROM EST_MAT_PRES P
                      WHERE P.CMATERIA = :MAT_CODE
                        AND P.CCARRERA = :COD_CARRERA
                       INTO :V_CMATERIA,
                            :V_CCARRERA,
                            :V_CTIPO,
                            :V_CANT

                DO BEGIN

                IF (V_CTIPO = 1) THEN
                BEGIN
                     /*BUSCO SI ESA MATERIA YA FUE APROBADA*/
                     SELECT COUNT(*)
                       FROM EST_INSCRIPCION EI
                       JOIN EST_INSCRIPCION_DET EID ON (EID.CINSCRIPCION = EI.CINSCRIPCION)
                       JOIN EST_MAT_CAR EMC ON (EMC.CMATE = EID.CMATE)
                       JOIN EST_CARRERAS EC ON (EC.CCARRERA = EMC.CCARRERA)
                       JOIN EST_MATERIAS EM ON (EM.CMATERIA = EMC.CMATERIA)
                      WHERE EID.NOTA >= 10
                        AND EMC.CMATERIA = :V_CMATERIA
                        AND EMC.CCARRERA = :V_CCARRERA
                        INTO :V_PRELACION;

                        IF (V_PRELACION > 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT P.CMATERIA
                                                              FROM EST_MAT_PRES P
                                                             WHERE P.CMATERIA = :MAT_CODE
                                                               AND P.CCARRERA = :COD_CARRERA
                                                               AND P.CTIPO = 2)) THEN
                        SUSPEND;
                END

                IF (V_CTIPO = 2) THEN
                BEGIN

                     SELECT COALESCE(SUM(EM.UC),'0') AS UC
                       FROM EST_INSCRIPCION EI
                       JOIN EST_INSCRIPCION_DET EID ON (EID.CINSCRIPCION = EI.CINSCRIPCION)
                       JOIN EST_MAT_CAR EMC ON (EMC.CMATE = EID.CMATE)
                       JOIN EST_CARRERAS EC ON (EC.CCARRERA = EMC.CCARRERA)
                       JOIN EST_MATERIAS EM ON (EM.CMATERIA = EMC.CMATERIA)
                      WHERE EID.NOTA >= 10
                        AND EI.CALUMNO = :P_ALUMNO
                       INTO :V_UC;

                       IF (V_UC >= V_CANT) THEN
                       SUSPEND;

                END
                END

         ELSE

         SUSPEND;
        END
END
```

El cual recibe el alumno y la carrera, si el alumno ha cursado antes una carrera y no ha pasado la materia la devuelve, de lo contrario devuelve las que puede ver.

:)